# Cursor move to the next line using textview

Tags: objective-c, ios

Hi friends I am trying to move curser move to the next line. it is worked but when I enter a character in textview curser again back to first line. please help me any one. I am writing below code.

```
if (textView == mailBodyTxtVew)
    {

        textView.text= [textView.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        //[textView resignFirstResponder];
       // return NO;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.text= [textView.text stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
```